# Elastic Search: include multiple field in query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic Search.I want to include multiple field in my search query something like:

```
      Title=my title and city=mycity or country = mycountry
```

How can I execute this kind of query using java client? I tried this

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("titan")
    .setTypes("vertex")
    .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.fieldQuery("title", "mytitle"))
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.fieldQuery("city", "mycity"))
    .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do [booleanQuery](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/query-dsl-queries.html#bool) there, I believe.

Something like:

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("titan")
    .setTypes("vertex")
    .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .must(QueryBuilders.fieldQuery("title", "mytitle"))
    .should(QueryBuilders.fieldQuery("city", "mycity"))
    .should(QueryBuilders.fieldQuery("country", "mycountry")))
    .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

The rules for boolean queries, in a nutshell, are that all `must` clauses are expected to be true, and at least one from the `should` clauses are expected to be true (the amount of should clauses which has to be true can be changed, one is the default).

Comment: `.must(QueryBuilders.fieldQuery("country", "IN"))` it work but if i use `.must(QueryBuilders.fieldQuery("country", "in"))` it doesnt. why?

Comment: Perhaps you country field is not analyzed?

Comment: then why it  is fetching for `IN`

Comment: I guess because when it's indexing the data, the country field is provided as "IN", and perhaps in the mapping it is specified as "not analyzed". that means it's not tokenized and taken as-is (case-sensitive, among other things). But it's just a guess, for the exact answer you need to know how the data are indexed.